# How do I add an event handler to a Button in Listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview, button, checkbox

My items in `ListView` are generated using PHP and stored in a `MySQL` database.  How can I add an event handler function tied to the buttons? The process that I need is like this: when you click the button it will get the item and save it to other table, as well as get the current datetime also.

```
public class ViewBusFiveStudent extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private Button btntime;
private String JSON_STRING;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_busfour);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    getJSON();
}


private void showStudents(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
            String name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);

            HashMap<String,String> student = new HashMap<>();
            student.put(Config.TAG_ID,id);
            student.put(Config.TAG_NAME,name);
            list.add(student);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            ViewBusFiveStudent.this, list, R.layout.list_items,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_ID,Config.TAG_NAME},
            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getJSON(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(ViewBusFiveStudent.this,"Fetching Data","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showStudents();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_BUS_FOUR);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewBusFive.class);
    HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String studId = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
    intent.putExtra(Config.STUD_ID,studId);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**Here's my list_view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxPres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnTime"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnTime"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnTime"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnTime" />

    <Button
        android:text="TimeStamp"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnTime" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to know how to define the function called when the button is clicked and where can i place it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change the code for onitemclick, i can click the button in the listview but only one button is working/clickable.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    btnTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTime);
    btnTime.setTag(position);
    btnTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BusArrived();
        }

        public void BusArrived() {

            final String name = name1.getText().toString().trim();

            class SendStudent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

                ProgressDialog loading;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loading = ProgressDialog.show(ViewBusFiveStudent.this, "Saving Dismissal Time...", "Wait...", false, false);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ViewBusFiveStudent.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put(Config.KEY_STUD_NAME, name);

                    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                    String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_SAVING_TO_BUS_FIVE_TIME, params);
                    return res;
                }
            }

            SendStudent ae = new SendStudent();
            ae.execute();
        }
    });
}
```

Please Correct my mistake here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you set click listeners on subviews in the row layout when you bind data to the row. This happens inside the adapter. Since you are using an adapter provided by the framework, it doesn't have logic to add click listeners to buttons in your row, it only knows how to do simple bindings (e.g. strings into a `TextView`, etc). You will have to subclass `SimpleAdapter` (or something else, like `BaseAdapter`) and add the necessary logic yourself.

While you're at it, I suggest you switch to using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. This means using `RecyclerView.Adapter` instead of the one you are using now, which will force you to implement the data binding logic anyway so you can add click listeners to subviews of your row layout. Also, `ListView` has a lot of quirks and idiosyncrasies, including weird interactions when rows have subviews that are focusable (like a clickable `Button`). `RecyclerView` will be much better for you in that regard.

Comment: Can you show me some samples of RecyclerView and a funcgtioning button to it? I havent use RecyclerView yet. Thanks

Comment: @Siegrain I think you should look for a tutorial online, since there are lots of important differences between ListView and RecyclerView and a small code snippet would not do the subject justice.

Comment: Is RecyclerView easier then ListView? I see tutorials about button in a listview but no one has the answer because my items in the listview is in mysql.

Comment: @Siegrain RecyclerView is easier in that you can just put a click listener on the Button and everything just works. ListView is notorious for being difficult when you have focusable or clickable subviews of an item view (because ListView is very heavy-handed about managing touch interactions over its children). None of this has anything to do with the source of your data; whatever data you are using now for your ListView, you can use for your RecyclerView as well.